# VSTO Word AddIn 2007/2010 Disable Editing, like document management systems do

Tags: ms-word, vsto, add-in

Could you tell me please how it is possible to:

- somehow disable editing an open document?
- or get notified when the user is about to change the current document?

like some document management apps do: while the document is checked in they:

- do not allow modifications to it or
- when user tries to modify it he will be notified that the document is checked in so it should be checked out first

Answer (score 2):

1. Set the document protection type to [WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyReading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdprotectiontype.aspx) which is similar to opening word document from Email, Internet or SharePoint portal.
2. When the use click the Edit anyway yellow bar in the top [ProtectedViewWindowDeactivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.appevents_event.protectedviewwindowdeactivate.aspx) Event will occur where you can raise an alert.

Comment: 1. Document protection would be a good idea, but it required only non protected documents, so users cannot use this feature. This is not a good solution unfortunately.

Comment: 2. ProtectedViewWindowDeactivate is available from 2010 versions, but not in 2007.